# php form empty unless refresh resubmit

Tags: php, forms, post, page-refresh

I have read many many many posts on this topic but none seem to address my particular problem.

I have removed all php and html from my form and striped it back to the bare minimum to eliminate coding mistakes.

```
<form action="/profilesave.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a" />
    <input type="text" name="b" />
    <input type="text" name="c" />
    <input type="text" name="d" />
    <input type="text" name="e" />

    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

profilesave.php

```
<?php $data = file_get_contents('php://input'); ?>
<?php var_dump($data);?>
<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
```

Result:

> string '' (length=0)
>
> array (size=0)
>   empty

However if I hit refresh on the page I get:

> string 'a=test&b=test&c=test&d=test&e=test&f=test&g=test&h=test'
>   (length=55)
>
> array (size=8)
>   'a' => string 'test' (length=4)
>   'b' => string 'test' (length=4)
>   'c' => string 'test' (length=4)
>   'd' => string 'test' (length=4)
>   'e' => string 'test' (length=4)
>   'f' => string 'test' (length=4)
>   'g' => string 'test' (length=4)
>   'h' => string 'test' (length=4)

Can anyone tell me please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: So on the page with your original HTML, you hit submit, and nothing happens?  Then when you refresh the page you get the POST body back?

Comment: I was able to successfully get the results without refreshing. Something else is causing this. If you have both files inside the same folder, do `action="profilesave.php"` instead of `action="/profilesave.php"`

Comment: @MattyAyOh Exactly that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No luck with that suggestion thanks.

Comment: OK so form works fine from a remote client. It only fails when run from localhost. Could "profilesave.php" be loading before the form is fully submitted? Can I delay "profilesave.php" to load until after the form is fully submitted if this is the case? Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you can try sleep http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: what happens if in the PHP you only have that last line? `<?php var_dump($_POST);?>` perhaps reading the data in the previous line takes too long

Comment: Tried the sleep() function however I believe it may be stopping the form submission too.

Comment: Only added that line for debugging purposes. Forms were still returning empty before.